# Display list of values separated by commas without trailing comma

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, arrays, linq-to-sql

I have an ASP.Net-MVC app using LinqToSql.  I have a subcontracts table, a service_lines table and a mapping/link table Service_lineToSubcontracts which contains the subcontract_id and service_line_id.  On the subcontract view, I'd like to list the corresponding service lines.

This works, but has a trailing comma.

```
<% foreach (var sls in item.Service_lineToSubcontracts)
   { %>
   <%= Html.Encode(sls.service_line.service_line_name+", ") %>
<% } %>
```

I think I should be able to use something like `String.Join(", ", item.Service_lineToSubcontracts.ToArray())` but I'm unsure of how to get the array of service_line_names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
<%= Html.Encode(string.Join(", ",
item.ServiceLineNames.Select(x=>x.service_line_name).ToArray())) %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That led me in the right direction
`<%= Html.Encode(string.Join(", ", item.Service_lineToSubcontracts.Select(x => x.service_line.service_line_name).ToArray())) %>`

Comment: Great. I didn't quite understand how your classes were setup, so I did my best ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Keltex answer you can omit to call the `ToArray()` method since the `String.Join` method works with any `IEnumerable<T>`.

An hint for a more concise and customizable form is to override the `ToString()` method of the collection's element's class, in your case it could be done as:

```
public class Service_lineToSubcontract
{
  public Service_line service_line {get; set;}
  ...
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return service_line.service_line_name; // Or whatever you need
  }
}
```

and then use the more concise form:

```
<%= Html.Encode(String.Join(", ", item.Service_lineToSubcontracts)) %>
```

maybe this hint is not the best choice in this context but it simplify a lot when you have collections of key-value pairs or you need a comma separated list of descriptions made up from more then one property